# Установить Куку живущую до конца текущего дня

Tags: php, cookie

Хочу реализовать механизм подсчета уникальных пользователей (по ip) сайта. План такой:

В БД таблица с полями  `id   date   time   ip`

При посещении страницы скрипт проверит есть ли печенька-икс, если нет то, вытаскиваем из БД все строки в которых `date` == сегодняшняя дата, если в списке нет совпадений по ip, то вносим в БД и кладем печеньку-икс, со сроком годности до конца этого дня

**Э квэсчен**: как установить куку с таким сроком жизни? (Использовать серверное время разумеется) Т.к. я до этого всегда ставил лишь на месяцок, да на все страницы

`setcookie("key", "val", time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, "/" );`

PS Знаю что в MySQL такие назавния ячеек использовать не стоит, обозвал их так для простоты сути вопроса

PPS Если у вас есть предложение как это все реализовать более удобным способом - пожалуйста напишите) Сайт на самописном движе :)

Comment: Идея делать это так - целиком плохая, никакой уникальности по айпи, да даже по клиентам, вы не получите :)

Comment: Ну неужели вы не предложите свой вариант достижения поставленой задачи?

Comment: Определитесь с задачей, уники по ip или по какому критерию?)

Comment: Ну вы же критикуете (я это приветствую) по ip делать уникальность) Хочу услышать чем и как можно)

Comment: Если по ip - нафик печеньки, используйте серверную переменную REMOTE_ADDR и при каждом обращении пишите запрос в базу вида ```insert uniq_user(ip,timestamp,count)values($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR '],time()/86400,1) on duplicate key update set count = count+1```, в базу ограничение уникальности на колонки ip+timestamp, остальное база сделает за вас... по желанию расширяете набор данных и ограничение уникальности на больше кол-во данных :)

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Буду пробовать внедрить!)